# Data is not get added into database(firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written the code for adding offers into database under offers, but it's not working and offer is not get added into database. I don't know where I did I made a mistake. Please help me out to find the solution

addoffer.html

```
<html>
<head>   
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Company" >

                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Redeem Steps</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="steps" placeholder="Redeem Steps">




                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Here can be your description"></textarea>



                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" onclick="submitclick()">Add Offer</button>

        </form>
<script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBMC7E0Q2HmqxDnA-yqSslIOhOijC6LL4s",
          authDomain: "sample-51bb2.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://sample-51bb2.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "sample-51bb2",
          storageBucket: "sample-51bb2.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "917745166311"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
      </script>
       <script src="addoffer.js"></script>  
</body>    
</html>
```

addoffer.js

```
function submitclick()
{

var titled = document.getElementById("title").value;
var stepsd = document.getElementById("steps").value;
var descriptiond = document.getElementById("description").value;
var id=1;

console.log(titled);
console.log(stepsd);
console.log(descriptiond);

//var firebaseheadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("offers");


firebase.database().ref('offers/'+id).set({
    title : titled,
    redeem : stepsd,
    description : descriptiond
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // The write failed...
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    } else {
      // Data saved successfully!
    }
  });

  id++;
}
```

I have added the image of the database where I have added offers value manually

[image]

Comment: did you change your firebase rules in the firebase console?

Comment: no I havent change rules all are true

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<head>   
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase.js"></script> 
</head>
```

into this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
<head>
```

Comment: is there any error at all in the console when you open your web page?

Answer (score 0):

The data **is correctly** added to the database but with the id `1`, due to the code of your `submitclick()` function.

Each time you call this function you assign the value `1` to the local (for the function) variable `id`, so each time it writes (and overwrites, since you use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method) to the `offers/1` node.

The `id++` at the end of the function has no effect: the next call id is set to 1.

You should probably use the `push()` method that will generate a new id for your record (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push).

You could use a global `id` variable at the level of the page, but in this case you might have different users using the same `id`, so it is really recommended to use the `push()` method.

Comment: @Vinit Mapari Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?